# Best practice for storing global app settings in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know what the best practice is for storing global app settings for your app in firestore. For example if your app has a setting to enable notifications, a setting for what theme color to use, etc. How would you go about structuring your collection and document(s) to make it so you can easily read/write each individual setting.

The method I have tried is creating a Settings Object Model that contains all my apps global settings, then storing and reading the object from Firestore as a single Document - however anytime I want to update a setting I have to retrieve the entire Settings Object from firestore then re-write the entire object back to Firestore after making the change to only a single setting.

Comment: I would think that a collection inside user profile (if you have one) should be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The method I have tried is creating a Settings Object Model that contains all my apps global settings, then storing and reading the object from Firestore as a single Document

That's a very convenient way of doing that.

> however anytime I want to update a setting I have to retrieve the entire Settings Object from firestore then re-write the entire object back to Firestore after making the change to only a single setting.

There is no need to get the document, in order to make an update. To change the value of a single property, you can simply use call `update("propertyName", "newValue")` function on your desired document reference.